# Can I store the yield value of sizeof of type size_t in an unsigned int object?

Tags: c, type-conversion, sizeof, unsigned-integer, size-t

`sizeof` is a standard C operator.

`sizeof` yields the size (in bytes) of its operand in type `size_t`, Quote from ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), 6.5.3.4/5. Phrases surrounded by `--` are my addition for clarification of context:

> The value of the result of both operators -- (sizeof and _Alignof) -- is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

Implicitly, if I want my program to be standard conform and want to use `sizeof`, I need to include one of the header files in which `size_t` is defined, because the value it yields is of type `size_t` and I want to store the value in an appropriate object.

Of course, in any program which would not be a toy program I would need at least one of these headers all the way up regardless but in a simple program I need to explictly include those headers, although I do not need them otherwise.

Can I use an unsigned int object to store the `size_t` value `sizeof` yields without an explicit cast?

Like for example:

```
char a[19];
unsigned int b = sizeof(a);
```

I compiled that with `gcc` and `-Wall` and `-Werror` option flag but it did not had anything to complain.

But is that standard-conform?

Comment: As long as the number is small enough to fit in an unsigned int.

Comment: @user253751 So as long as it fits in the range of an `unsigned int`, which is really not that small btw, this would be fine?

Comment: IMO `unsigned int b = sizeof(a);` is formally wrong because if `sizeof` is 64 bit and `unsigned int` is 32 bit you'll get into trouble if the size of `a` is larger than 0xffffffff (which is pretty unlikely though).

Comment: @Jabberwocky And what is with f.e. `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long int`? Would that be more appropriate?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio  The standard says `long int` is larger than or equal to the size of type `int`, so no there is no guarantee. The best would be to use `size_t`. But as I mentioned before, if your object sizes are "reasonable", you can go pragmatic and just use any unsigned 32 bit type.

Comment: *Can I use an `unsigned int` object to store the `size_t` value `sizeof` yields without an explicit cast?*  Why deliberately introduce a latent bug?  What's "reasonable" today might be much larger in the future.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: `unsigned int b = sizeof(a);` is not “formally wrong” unless you can cite a formal rule, e.g. a quotation from the C standard, saying it is wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I completely understand your concern and I probably would not implement it that way in any meaningful program, just to be sure everything is safe as possible, but I´m asking more for curiosity if there would be any issues for doing so, which seem, apart of considering the amount of size `a` could have in memory and providing a appropriate unsigned integer type else, to not exist.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "formally wrong" is probably a bad language choice.

Comment: A lot of headers pull in `size_t`, like `stdio.h`. I would personally just `#include <stddef.h>` and be done with it, which would be a lot less text than typing up an SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is permissible but it is your responsibility to provide that there will not be an overflow storing  a value of the type `size_t` in an object of the type `unsigned int`. For unsigned integer types overflow is well-defined behavior.

However it is a bad programming style to use types that were not designed to store values of a wider integer type. This can be a reason of hidden bugs.

Usually the type `size_t` is an alias for the type `unsigned long`. On some 64-bit systems, the type `unsigned long` has the same size as the type `unsigned long long`, which is 8 bytes instead of the 4 bytes that `unsigned int` can be stored in.

Comment: Ok, the issue with the storage space is noted. Thank you very much. But it would be completely correct if I would use for example `unsigned long long` instead of using `size_t`? There is nothing to complain about?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio but what's wrong with using `size_t` anyway?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio There will not be a problem. However it will confuse readers of the code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Just to avoid including the header. Nothing more nothing less. This question is mainly just asking for curiosity. But I wondering if there are any functions which require an explicit `size_t` parameter instead of for example `unsigned long long` if I would need to use `b` later.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio In fact all standard C string functions require a parameter of the type size_t abd have the return type size_t as for example strlen, strspn, strcspn and so on.

Comment: In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60562921/12139179) is said that if the yield size does not fit in an `unsigned int` it would be truncated automatically. What about that? Of course the size would be changed to a false value but it seems handled by the compiler.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio As i wrote the overflow for unsigned integer types is a well-defined behavior. However as you pointed out yourself you can get a wrong value.

Answer (score 3):

It is totally conformant, though if you have a very large object (typically 4GB or larger) its size may not fit into an `unsigned int`. Otherwise there is nothing to worry about.

Having said that, your question and this answer probably have more characters than you would save by not including an appropriate header in a lifetime worth of toy programs.

Comment: And if I would use `unsigned long int ` or  `unsigned long long int`?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio And why not, if you can explain the reason behind using them. Deliberately saving object sizes in smaller types I think mostly done because later than size has to be used in 32-bit context and using 64-bit type will require truncation in the end anyway. Making truncation earlier and with a constant is _much_ safer and can _save_ you from bugs, despite what others answers tell you.

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed. It is an [implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) ("as if by assignment"). See the section labelled "Integer conversions":

> A value of any integer type can be implicitly converted to any other integer type. Except where covered by promotions and boolean conversions above, the rules are:
>
> - if the target type can represent the value, the value is unchanged
> - otherwise, if the target type is unsigned, the value 2^(b-1), where b is the number of bits in the target type, is repeatedly subtracted or added to the source value until the result fits in the target type. In other words, unsigned integers implement modulo arithmetic.

In other words, this is always defined behaviour, but if the size is too big to fit in an `unsigned int`, it will be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

In principle it is ok. The `unsigned int` can handle almost any `sizeof` except artificially constructed exotic things.

P.S. I have seen code similar to yours even in Linux kernel modules.